# dotnet-core-uninstall not working from command line

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am working through the book C# 9.0 and .NET 5. On the section titled 'Removing old versions of .NET' it has several commands to make sure the most recent version is used.

`dotnet --list-sdks`

`dotnet --list-runtimes`

both work fine.

However, when I run the command
`dotnet-core-uninstall --all-previews-but-latest --sdk` I receive the error message that dotnet-core-uninstall isn't the name of a cmdlet, function, script file or operable program.

If I adjust the command from what is in the book to:
`dotnet -core-uninstall` I get the message 'unknown option: -core-uninstall' followed by the same output as `dotnet --help`

Likewise, if I run `dotnet -core-uninstall --all-previews-but-latest --sdk` the output tells me that -core-uninstall, --all-previews-but-latest and --sdk  are unknown options.

I then tried running these commands from the visual studio terminal, and had no luck either. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `dotnet-core-uninstall` is a [separate downloadable tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=macos), not part of the .NET Core SDK. It's not even a .NET Global tool. Did you download it?

Comment: `dotnet-core-uninstall` [can't be part of the SDK or a global tool](https://github.com/dotnet/cli-lab) because it wouldn't be able to remove the runtime version it's running on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dotnet-core-uninstall` is a [separate experimental tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=macos), not part of the .NET Core SDK. You need to [download from its Github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/cli-lab/releases) and install it.

The tool isn't a Global Tool because it wouldn't be able to remove the runtime it's running on. As the repo README explains:

> Since .NET Core Global Tools are runtime-dependent applications they use a version of the .NET Core Runtime that is installed on the machine. The purpose of the tool is to uninstall arbitrary .NET Core SDKs and Runtimes, so may attempt to uninstall the version that’s running the current process. When this happened, we didn’t find a way to recover from the error and uninstall other SDKs and Runtimes. We saw this as particularly problematic because users might not be clear what runtimes are in SDKs that are being uninstalled or which runtime is currently being used.

You may have installed a NET 6 preview for example and want to remove it. If `dotnet-core-uninstall` was a global tool, it would use the .NET 6 Preview runtime and wouldn't be able to remove it

Comment: oh sorry that makes so much sense!!! sorry for not realising the obvious, and thank you!

Comment: I tried to install it with `msiexec /i` but after that, the tool is still not available; where is it installed by default? (note: I'm testing in a GitHubActions VM)

Comment: The installer adds the tool to the PATH so it shouldn't matter where it's installed. If you run it with an admin account, it's added to the system PATH variable so it's available to all users. If your script can't find it, it means the *script* executes with a different PATH. The installation folder appears when you install interactively, `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet-core-uninstall`. The folder `C:\Program Files (x86)` is the default location for all 32-bit applications