# Uninstall .NET SDK 8.0

Tags: .net

I am trying to uninstall .NET SDK 8.0 and I cannot.

I don't remember installing it manually, so it is not available to be removed using Control Panel.

I think it might have been installed with a Visual Studio Preview update (since it was listed in the features of the VS 2022 installer). So I removed VS 2022 Preview completely.

But when using `dotnet --list-sdks` it is still there.

Then I tried to use the `dotnet-core-uninstall` tool but I get the following message:

> Uninstallation not allowed. This tool cannot uninstall .NET Core SDKs with version 8.0.0 or above.

Is there any other way to remove it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68194988/dotnet-core-uninstall-not-working-from-command-line

Comment: @Taco Thanks for the link, that that's not exactly related. The question is for uninstalling old SDK versions, which is no my case. Anyway, what is in that question is exactly what I explained I tried to do in the question above and it doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you trying to uninstall .NET 8 SDK? If you want to use an older version to build, use a `global.json` file that specifies which SDK version you want to use. As for `installed with a Visual Studio Preview` both .NET 8 and a stable Visual Studio version that supports it were released last month. .NET 8 is a Long Term Support version so you have to migrate to it sooner or later. .NET 7 reaches end-of-support in 6 months

Comment: Yes, I agree I'll have to migrate soon, but right now I just need to be able to build my project again. It started not building after .NET 8 was installed and I couldn't figure out why. But it is building in machines that doesn't have .NET 8 installed yet.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/cli-lab/issues/273

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks a lot! This should be an answer!

Comment: It very much _**can**_ be uninstalled by any of the following events: a nearby star going supernova, a killer solar flare, nuclear holocaust, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .Net versions earlier than .Net 6 and have installed .Net SDK 8 on your machine, this issue may occur. .Net 8 does not support duplicate files in the publish directory. As a result, it is failing to load runtime.

**Steps for manually deleting an SDK or Runtime:**

Run

> dotnet --info

and note the base path, e.g.

> Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk

**To remove an SDK:**

The dotnet/sdk directory (e.g. C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk) will have a sub-directory for each installed sdk version.
Within the dotnet/sdk directory, delete the sdk version directory (e.g. 8.0.100-rc.2.23502.2).

**To remove a runtime:**

The dotnet/shared directory (e.g. C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App) will have sub-directories for different runtimes (e.g. Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and Microsoft.NETCore.App). Each runtime directory will have version sub-directories.
For each relevant runtime, delete the version directory.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when updating Visual Studio from 17.5.1 to 17.8.6. I resolved the issue by reverting VS to 17.5.1 using Visual Studio Installer. It looks like VS Installer installs dotnet 8 with the new version and there is no way to remove it manually using the dotnet uninstaller command line tool or windows powershell admin commands.